# Why are not Laravel instances shared by default?

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have been surprised to discover that Laravel instances are not shared by default.

The "simplest" way I have found to declare a provider is the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use App\SomeService;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SomeServiceServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    public function register() {
        $this->app->singleton(SomeService::class);
    }

    public function provides() {
        $provides = parent::provides();
        $provides[] = SomeService::class;
        return $provides;
    }

}
```

TMHO the "standard" service in a dependency injection container is a shared instance. I am curious about why they choose this approach ?

And as a bonus, if you know a simpler way to declare a shared instance.

Comment: Are you asking why they don't use singletons more often?  I'm a little confused what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, in my opinion it should be a logical default (to avoid resource consumption)

Comment: Only if the class was designed to be shared.  There are lots of cases where you wouldn't want stale instance data.

Comment: Yes, it depends a lot on how you manage state.